# error with checkmark code

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uikit

In my `cellForRow` code I have the following and am getting an error saying nothing is being returned. What have I done wrong? Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) 
    { 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } 
    else
    { 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } 
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the function with the debugger?

Answer (score 3):

This is an endless loop: `UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

This should be:

```
static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"some_identifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] autorelease]
}
```

Comment: While you are correct about cell creation, this doesn't create an infinite loop. This sends the message `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to an instance of `UITableView`. The method it is being sent from is `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` on `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: I added that and it still does the same thing. Here it is:

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

Comment: if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }
    
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }     return cell;
}

Comment: still can't get my array to load with the code above, as it was loading before I added the checkmark code in.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will look something like this (for the most Basic Table View)

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView :(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier ";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex :row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:50];

    return cell;
}
```